# jquery datatable footer gets appended instead of using destroy

Tags: jquery, datatables

My jQuery datatable footer gets appended instead of using destroy function. I am creating a new DataTable on click of a another DataTable's row, on every click I create new DataTable as per the row which i clicked. When I recreate the new DataTable using `'destroy': true`, the prior loaded DataTable footer exist and new Table footer gets appended with its Footer, so both footer exist.

I also tried `$('#attachmentData').dataTable().destroy();` but it gives an error in my code of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

So instead I use `'destroy': true` where it works fine but I get an issue of this footer append. Can you tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
$('#attachmentData').dataTable({
    'aoColumnDefs': [{ 
        "sClass": "hide_me", 
        "aTargets": [0] 
    }],
    'destroy': true,
    'data': response,
    'columns': [{
        "title": "Attachment UId",
        "data": "AttachmentUid"
    }, {
        "title": "Attachment Name",
        "data": "AttachmentName"
    }, {
        "title": "Attachment Type",
        "data": "AttachmentType"
    }, {
        "title": "Created On",
        "data": "CreatedOn"
    }, {
        "title": "Printout",
        "data": "Printout"
    }]
});
```

Comment: try to add 'bSort': false

Answer (score 0):

To destroy a table manually in DataTables 1.10, you need to call API methods as shown below. See [API](http://datatables.net/reference/api/) for more information.

```
$('#attachmentData').dataTable().api().destroy();
```

or

```
$('#attachmentData').DataTable().destroy();
```

It seems that DataTables doesn't update a footer using `columns.title` option. See [columns.title](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title), it only mentions updating `<thead>` element.

The workaround is to update the footer yourself, for example:

```
 $('#attachmentData tfoot tr').html(
    '<th>Attachment UId</th>' +
    '<th>Attachment Name</th>' +
    '<th>Attachment Type</th>' +
    '<th>Created On</th>' +
    '<th>Printout</th>'
);
```

See example below for code and demonstration.

```js
var response = [
   {
     "AttachmentUid": 0,
     "AttachmentName": "AttachmentName",
     "AttachmentType": "AttachmentType",
     "CreatedOn": "CreatedOn",
     "Printout": '<button class="btn" type="button">Click me</button>'
   },
   {
     "AttachmentUid": 0,
     "AttachmentName": "AttachmentName",
     "AttachmentType": "AttachmentType",
     "CreatedOn": "CreatedOn",
     "Printout": '<button class="btn" type="button">Click me</button>'
   },
   {
     "AttachmentUid": 0,
     "AttachmentName": "AttachmentName",
     "AttachmentType": "AttachmentType",
     "CreatedOn": "CreatedOn",
     "Printout": '<button class="btn" type="button">Click me</button>'
   }
];
     
     
$(document).ready(function() {
   initTable();

  $('#example').on('click', '.btn', function(){
      $.each(response, function(index, obj){
         obj["AttachmentUid"]++;
      });
    
      initTable();
   });
});

function initTable(){
   var rnd = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1); 
  
   // Update footer headings
   $('#example tfoot tr').html(
      '<th>Attachment UId ' + rnd + '</th>' +
      '<th>Attachment Name ' + rnd + '</th>' +
      '<th>Attachment Type ' + rnd + '</th>' +
      '<th>Created On ' + rnd + '</th>' +
      '<th>Printout ' + rnd + '</th>'
  );
  
   $('#example').dataTable({
    'aoColumnDefs': [{ 
        "sClass": "hide_me", 
        "aTargets": [0] 
    }],
    'destroy': true,
    'data': response,
    'columns': [
      {
        "title": "Attachment UId " + rnd,
        "data": "AttachmentUid"
      }, {
        "title": "Attachment Name " + rnd,
        "data": "AttachmentName"
      }, {
        "title": "Attachment Type " + rnd,
        "data": "AttachmentType"
      }, {
        "title": "Created On " + rnd,
        "data": "CreatedOn"
      }, {
        "title": "Printout " + rnd,
        "data": "Printout"
      }
    ]
   });
}
```

```html
<link href="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://datatables.net/release-datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AttachmentUid</th>          
            <th>AttachmentName</th>
            <th>AttachmentType</th>
            <th>CreatedOn</th>
            <th>Printout</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
 
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>AttachmentUid</th>          
            <th>AttachmentName</th>
            <th>AttachmentType</th>
            <th>CreatedOn</th>
            <th>Printout</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
 
</table>
```